# Configure a MC Journey with decision splits evaluated against a field from SFDC

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

What is the best way to configure a MC Journey with decision splits evaluated against a field from SFDC? As the value of the field changes over time the decision split should evaluate against the current value.

I have a salesforce data entry source based-off Campaign and Campaign Members.  The decision split evaluates Campaign Member status after a set date.  The Campaign Member Status changes in SFDC over time, a second decision split re-evaluates the status at a later time.

Both decision splits are based off Contact Data of the DE from the Entry Source created by MC.  The decision split evaluated the static data and not against the current value from SFDC.  The problem is that the statuses are not refreshed in the DE when status values are changed in SFDC.

I also attempted to select a different Contact Data, e.g. synchronized salesforce data extension, but decision split only shows Entry Source DE.  See screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you enable Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connect, a new Attribute Group gets added in Data Designer in Contact Builder in the Business Unit where the connection is done. An example can be seen below:

[image: Data Designer]

If you are building your journey in a different BU, you will need to use a Query Activity (built in ENT BU), along with Shared Data Extensions, to push data from Synchronised Data Extensions, and into the appropriate BU. Once done, you can add a new Attribute Group, adding this Shared Data Extension to this new Attribute Group. Ensuring the fields you need in your decision split, are passed on to the DE in Attribute Group.

Doing this, the Attribute Group and data therein will become available under Contact Data in Decision Split.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm out of office for couple of days. I will check on this and get back to you!

Comment: Hi @codeyinthecloud - did you manage taking a look at the solution?

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. Actually we now replicated campaign table for live sync in marketing cloud and that kind of solved the issue

Comment: Hi @LukasLunow - is it still like the only solution? I can share synchronized data from parent BU now but it does not show up in "Data Designer" in child BU. Should I go for your solution or maybe Data Designer need some time after I established "Share Across Enterprise"